# 502 Bad Gateway error on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, php-5.4, php-5.5

I have a problem on my nginx server, so I tried to update php from 5.3 to 5.5 with this commands:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Earlier work all right but before I make this update I get 502 Bad Gateway nginx 1.1.19. This is beacause I need to update and the nginx server?please help me
p.s.
If I make sudo netstat -lntp | grep ':80' :

```
tcp  0  0.0.0.0:80  LISTEN 1352/nginx
```

Comment: what do you see in the error log?

Comment: 2014/07/28 06:29:23 [error] 4238#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.82, server: symblog.com, request: "GET /2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "symblog.com", referrer: "http://symblog.com/"

Comment: I found the error, need to add in nginx config file : fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;